# Python - Adding new variables automatically

Tags: python, variables, input, dictionary

Good evening guys,
Im thinking about making a program sometime in the week where it stores usernames and passwords. The user will be able to directly input their own username and chosen password and it stores them. The program will need to be able to store a username as a variable so what im asking is how can python create a new variable from a user input? because to store usernames it would have to have an infinite list of variables so it needs to be able to generate its own.
I hope you understand what im asking :)

---

I am also wondering, if this is not possible, would i be able to add their username to a dictionary from an input.

Really baffled by this at the moment and would appreciate any help :)

Comment: An "infinite list of variables" - sounds like you need an ordinary `list`. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) part of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But that is exactly what lists and dictionaries are for. Variable names are not data: as you say, the more people you have, the more variables you'd need to create. Whereas you could easily store a password in a dictionary keyed by the username:

```
import getpass
users = {}
username = raw_input('Enter your username?')
password = getpass.getpass('Enter your password?')
users[username] = password
```

I hope you know, though, that the dictionary will only remain as long as your program is running. If you want it to be permanent, you'll need to store it somewhere, say in a database or a disk file.

Comment: And preferably do something with the password so it's not in cleartext!

Answer (score 0):

As Sukrit said to store username and password values you would assign the raw_input to a variable.

However to have the "dictionary" feature you mention, you might want to interface with a database. In that case the link below shows a tutorial on connecting to a MySQL database and executing queries.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm